# what is the operator precedance/order of execution for && in javascript

Tags: javascript

what is the operator precedance/order of execution for `&&` in javascript

```
str = "string"
iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()
while ( result = iterator.next() && !result.done ) { // Error result is not defined..Is it not a left to right evaluatation
  console.log( result.value )
}
```

Changing this by adding parenthesis seem to do the trick ...

```
str = "string"
iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()
while ( ( result = iterator.next() ) && !result.done ) { // Parenthesis seem to take precedence
  console.log( result.value )
}
```

Comment: seems your code is error,should be `iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]()`

Comment: Well, apparently it is higher than the precedence of the `=` assignment operator… What exactly is your question? You already figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because you have assignment, so it is executed as:

```
result = (iterator.next() && !result.done)
```

instead of

```
(result = iterator.next()) && !result.done
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2):

As per the table in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) here

**logical AND** `&&` has *Precedence* of 6 while **equal to** `=` has *Precedence* of `3`, which means `&&` will get executed first since it has higher precedence unless you use parenthesis `()` (which has precedence of 20 - maximum)

This explains the result you get in your first code

`( result = iterator.next() && !result.done )` =>  becomes

```
( result = (iterator.next() && !result.done) ) //while result is already undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the precedences here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

As you find out `=` is last executed, in every case, when no parens are present